# Can't play videos from SD card using native Android video player

Tags: android, android-video-player

I'm trying to play video stored on the SD card and I'm getting an error each time. I'll post my code first followed by the stack trace.

```
protected void launchVideo( Uri data ) {

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        intent.setDataAndType( data, "video/*" );
        startActivity( intent );
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showErrorDialog( "Unable to open video." );
    }
}
```

An example Uri that is passed in: `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20120312_152550.mp4`

Every time I get an `ActivityNotFoundException`. Here's the stack trace:

```
03-30 12:23:17.890: W/System.err(22867): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/Default/18421.mp4 typ=video/* }
03-30 12:23:17.890: W/System.err(22867):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
03-30 12:23:17.890: W/System.err(22867):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
03-30 12:23:17.890: W/System.err(22867):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
03-30 12:23:17.898: W/System.err(22867):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:678)
03-30 12:23:17.898: W/System.err(22867):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:783)
03-30 12:23:17.898: W/System.err(22867):    at com.my.app.GalleryFragment.launchVideo(GalleryFragment.java:222)
```

Am I using the wrong syntax for feeding in a local video? I've browsed my phone and I can verify the video is there, I've moved it onto my desktop and it plays. I've created a `File` using the Uri data and called `exists()` and it returns true.

My app plays web videos fine using this method, and in fact the video I'm attempting to play streams from the web fine. I have multiple local videos, none of them work.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I couldn't play video from the SD card, but I found a solution.

Instead of giving the file path to the video, I'm giving the content Uri using `Uri.withAppendedParts(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Integer.toString(id));`. This works and is playing video now.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   Uri name = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Test_Movie.m4v");  
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   String type = "video/mp4";
   intent.setDataAndType(name, type);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, it ends up being the same Uri data, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found following better solution for this problem. Please take a look.

[Intent.ACTION_VIEW video: external storage video "Sorry, this video cannot be played", but in regular android player, it is playable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133140/intent-action-view-video-external-storage-video-sorry-this-video-cannot-be-pl/21012335#21012335)