# Intent.ACTION_VIEW video: external storage video "Sorry, this video cannot be played", but in regular android player, it is playable

Tags: android, android-intent, android-video-player

So I'm playing a video from external storage(sdcard), I'm having a problem with playing the video and this is my code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
```

It prompts "Sorry, this video cannot be played", but in regular android player, it is playable. I printed the url and this is what I got:

```
VideoPlayer url: file:///mnt/sdcard/foldername/video-2012-12-26-21-26--44.mp4
```

Is it a problem with the uri? If no, can you point me to the right direction. Also if I try a foldername that have a dot(.) will I have a problem?

```
url = file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.project/video-2012-12-26-21-26--44.mp4
```

Thanks.

Edit: Since my real problem was not solve, and nobody want to answer anymore, I open up a new question:
[Android: Video is playable from gallery but when I play it using Intent.ACTION_VIEW type video, cannot play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138130/android-video-is-playable-from-gallery-but-when-i-play-it-using-intent-action-v)

**Partial Answer to my problem:**

The problem occurs because of naming convention. I think the player doesn't accept file names that have "--" in it. So I solved this problem by changing the file name format.

//Disclaimer: I don't have a full explanation and source but this info is just deduced from my workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make sure you are passing right sdcard path with Intent. best way is use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) for getting SDCARD path instead of passing static string :

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdCard, "/foldername/video-2012-12-26-21-26-44.mp4");

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Okay so I implemented the code above, the path is correct, the file exist (I've checked it), but the video is still not playable. I've tried both "/com.example.project/video-2012-12-26-21-26-44.mp4" and "/foldername/video-2012-12-26-21-26-44.mp4" (both have the file). But it is still not working. Any more suggestions? I repeat, the file is playable by browsing it in the gallery, but not using the code.

Comment: @Marl : k give me a link for Video

Comment: I guess I partially know what happened, I think this problem is due to naming convention. When I renamed the file into a simpler one, the video is playable. But when I use my original filename format, the video is not. So I solve this problem by changing my filename format. Particular example: having "--" in the filename will make the video unplayable.

Comment: i wan't open url video

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert path to real path.
For example if you have path like content://flod/123
You need to convert it to path like foldername/file.mp4 + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

So your path string will be:
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "foldername/file.mp4";
Then you need to convert it to file:

File file = new File(path);

And in the end use this in the line:

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");