# Android: Video is playable from gallery but when I play it using Intent.ACTION_VIEW type video, cannot play

Tags: android, video, android-intent

[Here is my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133140/intent-action-view-video-external-storage-video-sorry-this-video-cannot-be-pl/)

I've implemented the answer there but still the problem persist.

Here is the gist:
So I'm playing a video from external storage(sdcard), I'm having a problem with playing the video and this is my code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
```

It prompts "Sorry, this video cannot be played", but in the gallery, it is playable. I printed the url and this is what I got:

```
VideoPlayer url: file:///mnt/sdcard/foldername/video-2012-12-26-21-26--44.mp4
```

The file exist from the answer that I got. But still the problem persist, and I have no idea what went wrong.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks

Edit:To those who didn't see the answer in the first question. I've already implemented this:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdCard, "/foldername/video-2012-12-26-21-26--44.mp4");

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");

startActivity(intent);
```

The file exist since I've checked it. I'm wondering if there is a problem with the file naming convention.

Also I'm debugging from my device, Samsung Galaxy Ace, Android 2.3.6, compiling with 4.2 sdk.

Edit 2:
I've tried renaming the video into simpler one and now the video works, my guess is that the the file has a filename length limitation or an naming convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried different solution. But I guess the problem occurred because of naming convention. I have tried renaming the file into a simpler format and it works. Also the problem with my original file name is that I have a "--" in the file name.

Answer (score 5):

This code is from a working app that I made, try it out.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.parse("file://"+ file.getAbsolutePath()),
                    "video/*");
```

Comment: I've tried this, but still doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is a problem with the naming convention of the file.

Comment: you can try to change the file name before playing it, then if it work change it back to its actual name after playing it.

Comment: tried it, still doesn't work. I'm running the app in android 2.3.6

Comment: are you sure that the file path and name is the correct one? also do you get that error when trying to play it with a video player that you made or using the gallery one?

Comment: I know the file path and name is correct since I'm checking if it exist(file.exists()). I'll check if I can play a video that I created

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `file` scheme:

So you should use `intent.setDataAndType("file://" + uri, "video/*");`